# Running JSP files with tomcat 7

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat

Hi I just installed Apache Tomcat 7 and got the server running OK. When I entered localhost:8089 (8089 being the port I assigned to Tomcat 7) the apache website popped up and I   got to run some jsp examples and they opened correctly.

However now I wish to create a jsp file myself (I am trying tutorials for the very first time) and when I open them, only the source code I written is showing in the browser.

The example I am trying is this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
Hello World. <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</body>

</html>
```

and all I'm seeing in Chrome is :  `"Hello World. <%= new java.util.Date() %>"`

I am saving this file in this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\host-manager\WEB-INF\jsp
```

In WEB-INF there is an index.html file ready.

Am I doing something wrong? Where am I supposed to save my file? 
I tried watching tutorials on youtube but most of them were in arabic and I couldn't understand a thing!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 14):

Your JSP file must NOT be in WEB-INF.

You must create a directory named as you want (`myFirstWebApp` for example), put your JSP in any subdirectory you want except WEB-INF (for example `myFirstWebApp/foo/bar/hello.jsp`), then deploy the webapp by copying the myFirstWebApp firectory to the `webapps` directory of Tomcat. The JSP will then be accessible using the URL

```
http://localhost:8089/myFirstWebApp/foo/bar/hello.jsp
```

WEB-INF is where you put the files that you don't want to make accessible from the outside:

- the jars (under `WEB-INF/lib`),
- the classes (under `WEB-INF/classes`),
- the deployment descriptor (web.xml, optional in servlet 3.0 webapps configured through annotations),
- and any other file you want anywhere under WEB-INF (typically, configuration files).

Why don't you read the documentation? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

Answer (score 2):

Rename your jsp-file to:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\index.jsp
```

now, navigate to

```
http://localhost:8089/
```

Short and Easy.

Answer (score 2):

Put your jsp file in ROOT folder as

```
/Users/<username>/Desktop/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/test.jsp
```

Run your application like

http://localhost:8080/test.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Save your jsp file in your webapps directory with .jsp extention

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps
and types at the address bar of the browser-  http:\localhost:8089/exmp.jsp
and press Enter key